# Conversão de php form para smtp

Tags: php, javascript, smtp

É o seguinte, meu formulário ele nao tinha autenticação, mas o servidor do cliente requer autenticação, eu fiz com que ele autenticasse, mas agora ele não envia. será que poderiam me apontar os erros para que eu pudesse corrigir eles?

PHP antigo:

```
<?php
// Check for empty fields
if(empty($_POST['name']) || empty($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['message']) || !filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
echo json_encode(array('error'=>'true'));
return false;
}

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email_address = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$subject = ($_POST['subject'] ? $_POST['subject'] : "Website Contact   Form:  $name");



// Create the email and send the message
$to = 'email@to.com.br';// Add your email address inbetween the ''  replacing yourname@yourdomain.com - This is where the form will send a message to.
$email_subject = $subject;
$email_body = "You have received a new message from your website   contact form.\n\n"."Here are the details:\n\nName: $name\n\nLast Name:     $lastname\n\nEmail: $email_address\n\nPhone:  $phone\n\nMessage:\n$message";
$headers = "From: noreply@yourdomain.com\n"; // This is the email address the generated message will be from. We recommend using something like noreply@yourdomain.com.
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address"; 
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
echo json_encode(array('success'=>'true'));
return true;            
?>
```

PHP novo:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
require("phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php");
require("phpmailer/class.smtp.php");

// Check for empty fields
if(empty($_POST['name']) || empty($_POST['email']) ||   empty($_POST['message']) ||     !filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
echo json_encode(array('error'=>'true'));
return false;
}

$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // Usar autenticação SMTP (obrigatório para smtp.seudomínio.com.br)
$mail->Username = 'leadsvw@grupomenegalli.com.br'; // Usuário do servidor SMTP (endereço de email)
$mail->Password = '*********'; // Senha do servidor SMTP (senha do email usado)

$mail->From = "leadsvw@grupomenegalli.com.br"; // Seu e-mail
$mail->Sender = "leadsvw@grupomenegalli.com.br"; // Seu e-mail
$mail->FromName = "Dimasa VW"; // Seu nome

$mail->AddAddress('leadsvw@grupomenegalli.com.br', 'Dimasa');

$mail->IsHTML(true);

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email_address = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];

$mail->Subject = "Contato a partir do site Dimasa VW";

$message = "
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Contato a partir do site Dimasa VW</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <p>
            Nome: $name<br>

            Email: $email_address<br>

            Telefone: $phone<br>

            Mensagem: $message
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
";

$mail->Body = $message;
$xx = $mail->Send();

$mail->ClearAllRecipients();
$mail->ClearAttachments();

if($xx){
echo json_encode(array('success'=>'true'));
return true;
}           
?>
```

O script eu não alterei, estou usando o mesmo para o novo:

```
$(function() {
$("input,textarea").jqBootstrapValidation({
preventSubmit: true,
submitError: function($form, event, errors) {
    // additional error messages or events
},
submitSuccess: function($form, event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // prevent default submit behaviour
    // get values from FORM
    var topic = $("select#user-topic").val();
    var name = $("input#user-name").val();
    var email = $("input#user-email").val();
    var phone = $("input#user-phone").val();
    var message = $("textarea#user-message").val();
    var firstName = name; // For Success/Failure Message
    // Check for white space in name for Success/Fail message
    if (firstName.indexOf(' ') >= 0) {
        firstName = name.split(' ').slice(0, -1).join(' ');
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: "../../mail/contact_me.php",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            topic: topic,
            name: name,
            email: email,
            phone: phone,
            message: message
        },
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
            if(data.error){
                // Fail message
                $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>");
                $('#success > .alert-danger').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;").append("</button>");
                $('#success > .alert-danger').append("<span>Perdão " + firstName + ", parece que ocorreu uma falha no envio, tente novamente!</span>");
                $('#success > .alert-danger').append('</div>');
                //clear all fields
                $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
            }
            else if(data.success){
                // Success message
                $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-success'>");
                $('#success > .alert-success').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;").append("</button>");
                $('#success > .alert-success').append("<span>Sua mensagem foi enviada com sucesso </span>");
                $('#success > .alert-success').append('</div>');
                //clear all fields
                $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
            }
        }
    })
},
filter: function() {
    return $(this).is(":visible");
},
});
});


/*When clicking on Full hide fail/success boxes */
$('#name').focus(function() {
    $('#success').html('');
});
```

Se tiver que alterar o script, por favor me avise também.

Comment: Downvoter, você poderia explicar para o Pedro o que ele fez de errado?

Answer (score 1):

Deve-se atentar para a autenticação smtp:

```
$mail->SetLanguage("br");
$mail->IsSMTP(); // Define que a mensagem será SMTP
$mail->Host = smtp.seudomínio.com.br; // Endereço do servidor SMTP (caso queira utilizar a autenticação, utilize o host smtp.seudomínio.com.br)
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // Usar autenticação SMTP (obrigatório para smtp.seudomínio.com.br)
$mail->SMTPSecure = ''; // Protocolo ssl ou tls
$mail->Port = 'port'; // Porta do servidor a ser usado
$mail->Username = ''; // Usuário do servidor SMTP (endereço de email)
$mail->Password = ''; // Senha do servidor SMTP (senha do email usado)
```

Acrescentando as linhas que faltam, deve autenticar tranquilamente.

Comment: eu coloquei isto em meu código, ainda nao deu certo

Comment: Mande o erro que deu. E qual e o servidor que está usando?

Comment: não chega a aparecer algum erro, ele apenas não envia, esse é o link da [página](http://dimasavolkswagen.grupomenegalli.com.br/contato.html)